# Writing a for loop condition in pseudocode

Tags: pseudocode

How do I write a program to accept a number from the user 100 times using a for loop, with just the for loop syntax only? No programming language is required, just the syntax in pseudocode form.

I tried this format but my teacher did not accept it.

```
begin
    numeric num
    accept num
       for (num=1;num<=100;num+1)
            begin
            end
```

Comment: Given you're requirement of "accept a number from the user 100 times" this would not suffice. You are doing "accept num" only once. Move it to inside the loop. And change the name of the loop variable to not be the same. Like ```for iter=1,100 do: accept num; work with num;```